# Join Ansible Vars with ansible facts in conf file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm new to ansible and had an issue with getting vars with the hostname as following

```
variable_name:
    localhost: my_pc
```

In the jinja template(used for the property file), I need the var calling using ansible facts as the output should be variable_name.localhost (variable_name.<ansible_hostname>)

```
// following didn't worked
{{ variable_name.ansible_hostname }} // error
{{ variable_name }}.{{ ansible_hostname }} // {'localhost: my_pc'}.'localhost'
{{ [variable_name, ansible_hostname ] | join(".") }} // {'localhost: my_pc'}.'localhost'
{{ variable_name.{{ ansible_hostname }} }} // error
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: => `{{ variable_name[ansible_hostname] }}`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-nested-variables

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @Zeitounator, it works using

```
{{ variable_name[ansible_hostname] }}
```